# iOS drawing in CALayers drawInContext is either pixelated or blurry on retina

Tags: ios, core-graphics, calayer, retina

I have a custom `UIView` that draws something in an overwritten

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
```

this works fine and gives sharp results on retina screens.

However, now I would like to make the properties on which the drawing is based animatable. Creating animatable properties seems to be possible only on the `CALayer`, so instead of doing the drawing in `UIView`, I create a custom `CALayer` subclass and do the drawing inside

```
- (void) drawInContext:(CGContextRef)ctx
```

I use pretty much the exact same drawing code in this function as I used in the `drawRect` function of the custom `UIView`.

The result looks the same - however, it's not retina resolution but pixelated (large square pixels)

if I put

```
self.contentsScale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;
```

To the beginning of my `drawInContext` implementation, then instead of a pixelated result, I get a blurry result (as if the rendering is still performed in non-retina resolution and then upscaled to retina resolution).

what's the correct way to render sharp retina paths in `CALayers` `drawInContext` ?

here are some screenshots (the blue line is part of the custom drawing in question. the yellow part is just an image)

Drawn inside custom UIView's `drawRect`:

[image]

Drawn inside custom CALayer's `drawInContext`:

[image]

Drawin inside custom CALayer's `drawInContext`, with setting `self.contentScale` first:

[image]

For completeness, here's (a stripped down version of the) drawing code:

```
//if drawing inside custom UIView sublcass:
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGContextRef currenctContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    [[UIColor blackColor] set];

    CGContextSetLineWidth(currenctContext, _lineWidth);
    CGContextSetLineJoin(currenctContext,kCGLineJoinRound);

    CGContextMoveToPoint(currenctContext,x1, y1);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(currenctContext,x2, y2);
    CGContextStrokePath(currenctContext);
}

//if drawing inside custom CALayer subclass:
- (void) drawInContext:(CGContextRef)ctx {
{
    //self.contentsScale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;

    CGContextRef currenctContext = ctx;
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(currenctContext, [UIColor blackColor].CGColor);

    CGContextSetLineWidth(currenctContext, _lineWidth);
    CGContextSetLineJoin(currenctContext,kCGLineJoinRound);

    CGContextMoveToPoint(currenctContext,x1, y1);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(currenctContext,x2, y2);
    CGContextStrokePath(currenctContext);
}
```

To restate what I want to achieve: I want to achieve the same crisp retina rendering as in the `UIView` approach, but when rendering in `CALayer`

Comment: in retina display, you need to multiply the height and width by 2.

Comment: no, the size and location on screen is correct

Comment: I mean the screen you just create should be multiplied by 2, because retina display needs double resolution.

Comment: Thank you for trying to help, but I think you did not properly understand my problem here

Comment: What if you move `self.contentsScale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale` to layer initialization method?

Comment: Did you ever solve this?  I have the exact same issue, and using shouldRasterize and setting rasterizationScale have no effect.

Answer (score 18):

The issue is most likely to be contentScale here; be aware that if you're assigning this to a custom view by overriding its `layerClass` function, the layer's content scale may be reset. There may be some other instances in which this also happens. To be safe, set the content scale only after the layer has been added to a view.

Try assigning the main screen's scale to your custom layer during your custom view's init method. In Swift 3 that looks like this:

```
layer.contentsScale = UIScreen.mainScreen().scale
```

Or, in Swift 4:

```
layer.contentsScale = UIScreen.main.scale
```

Comment: Perfect this fixed the pixelated problems

Comment: That solved the problem, thank you! Swift 5 2021

Answer (score 9):

Are you using `shouldRasterize = YES` in the layer? Try drawing in the CALayer subclass but set the `rasterizationScale` to the screen's scale.

Comment: @AndresCanella on which device did you use 4.0 for rasterizationScale?

Comment: @Crashalot I ended up using screen scale * 2.0 on i6. I was loosing crispness on 4.0.

Answer (score 5):

After adding layer to its superlayer. set shouldRasterize to YES , set contentsScale and resterizatioinScale to screen scale:

```
[self.progressView.layer addSublayer:self.progressLayer];
self.progressLayer.shouldRasterize = YES;
self.progressLayer.contentsScale = kScreenScale;
self.progressLayer.rasterizationScale = kScreenScale;

CABasicAnimation *animate = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"progress"];// progress is a customized property of progressLayer
animate.duration = 1.5;
animate.beginTime = 0;
animate.fromValue = @0;
animate.toValue = @1;
animate.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
animate.removedOnCompletion = NO;
animate.repeatCount = HUGE_VALF;
[self.progressLayer addAnimation:animate forKey:@"progressAnimation"];
```